# <c:forEach> does not seem to find the iterated Map.Entry in the EL scope

Tags: jsf, foreach, hashmap, jstl

My problem is solved using lists instead of maps, but I have written down here because I don't understand what is wrong with maps.

I have a map defined in my view (*myView.java*):

```
private Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and it is populated dynamically by one method called from a commandButton action:

```
<p:commandButton 
    value="#{txt['form.view']}"
    process="@form"
    icon="ui-icon-search"
    action="#{myView.populateMap}"
    update=":myForEach"
/>
```

I put one item into the map, with dynamic key and value:

```
public void populateMap(){
        myMap.clear();
        myMap.put(getCode(this.param), getDetails(this.param));
    }
```

When I loop this map, it is not printing what is expected:

```
WholeMap: #{myView.myMap}<br/>
<c:forEach items="#{myView.myMap}" var="item">
    Key: #{item.key} Value: #{item.value}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Unexpectedly, the whole map is printed in the first line correctly, but item key and value is empty when I try to print them within the forEach.

It seems like it can't find the content of the map once it is changed from the view class. If I click again on the commandButton, it print successfully what is expected, only if the *populateMap* method put the same item into the map.

Comment: When you clicking on button then only  `populateMap()` added value in  `mymap` or `mymap`  have already added value when page rendered

Comment: So, `<c:forEach>` didn't work? How did you install JSTL? How did you register `xmlns:c` namespace? How does generated HTML output look like?

Comment: @BalusC: forEach worked, because literals are printed, but item.key and item.value are empty, despite map is properly printed just before forEach.

Comment: You mean, you're seeing `Key: <Value:` being printed as many times as there are entries in the map and not just once?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: I don't understand what you mean, but maybe the clue is in your lines. myMap has added value through the method, so if the page is rendered after the method is called, myMap should have the value added.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, it is printed. In the example there is only one line, because it has only one item, but I've tried with more items and it prints one line for each item. By the way, this "<" is a mistake in my writting. I've edited the question.

Comment: Rename `var="item"` to something else. It might be hijacked by another variable.

Comment: If @BaluC is already replying than  my view is not worthy :) He will tell you exact solution

Comment: @BalusC I renamed the _var_ but still the same. When click by second time and the map is overwritten by the method, I can see that _key_ keep the old string and _value_ is empty... (inside the loop, because the map outside has the current key and value...). Is it trying to find the value of the old key?

Comment: I can explain that, but then I can't explain why it worked with lists. Can you reconfirm that exactly the same use case really works with lists?

Comment: I just test the same example with List<String>, adding only the value as String (forgetting key), and it works. Don't you believe that looping maps in JSTL has a different behavior? It is as if it reads the map using a previous list of keys. When the maps is changed, it can't find the old keys, and the values are empty.

Comment: By the way, when I use maps, and I print the whole item inside the loop, it prints this:
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.MappedValueExpression$Entry@29c9da2 (i don't know if this means sth to you...)

Comment: Which Mojarra version are you using? Tried the latest?

Comment: I am using Mojarra 2.2.4 Do you think is too old? I will tried with latest, but I think It is not allowed in my project... Thank you!

Comment: Just to exclude one and other.

Comment: I've found this old post of you (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14343942/2098871) that could be a similar problem...