# How to display the result of a Map<String, Map<String, String>> on a datatable in JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, hashmap

Using JSF:

Is it possible to iterate over a `Map` whose values contain `Map`s?

I have a `Map` that looks like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> myMap;
```

I would like to iterate over `myMap` and display the result in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can for sure, every map can be iterated getting the [Entry Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), you will need to iterate in this case twice since you have a Map inside a Map...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Map< String, Map < String, String >> foo = new HashMap<String, Map < String, String >>();
    for (Entry<String, Map<String, String>> fooEntry : foo.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(fooEntry.getKey());
        for (Entry<String, String> fooValueEntry : fooEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(fooValueEntry.getKey());
            System.out.println(fooValueEntry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSF datatable component does not currently support iteration on a map (JSF 2.2).
You will have to do a little work of transformation or use a c:forEach.

More on this here : [Using java.util.Map in h:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343788/using-java-util-map-in-hdatatable)